# Как получить разницу между датами?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Имеется 2 даты в формате

```
hh.mm.ss-dd.MM.yyyy
```

Подскажите каким образом мне получить разницу между ними? в том же формате?

Comment: самый простой вариант - сконвертировать в число (long long) а дальше просто вычесть.

Comment: Можно перевести обе даты в количество секунд (например, [Unix time](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F)), вычесть и перевести обратно в нужный формат.

Comment: правильно - конвертировать в QDateTime, а там есть методы daysTo, secsTo

Comment: @KoVadim `secsTo` очень хороший метод.

Comment: Не ясно как вы хотите разницу в виде месяцев представлять, Например, если разница между датами 59 дней, то какой результат вы хотите (1 марта, 29 февраля, что-то другое)? Если разница в годах, то если вы хотите точность до секунды, то какие года вы имеете в виду (средний григорианский год, какой-то конкретный год в заданной часовой зоне, тропический год  в 2010, что-то другое)? Если хотите точность до часа, то стоит часовой пояс (локальное время, UTC) упомянуть (если заданные даты могут разное UTC смещение иметь, например, из-за наличия летнего/зимнего времени в выбранной зоне).

Comment: related: [Qt - Get the time span between two datetime objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17078598/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как в метках стоит Qt:

```
QString timeInterval(const QString& from, const QString& to, const QString& format = "hh.mm.ss-dd.MM.yyyy")
{
  QDateTime fromDt = QDateTime::fromString(from, format);
  QDateTime toDt = QDateTime::fromString(to, format);
  if (fromDt.isValid() && toDt.isValid()) {
    QDateTime interval = QDateTime::fromMSecsSinceEpoch(toDt.toMSecsSinceEpoch() - fromDt.toMSecsSinceEpoch());
    interval = interval.addYears(-1970);
    return interval.toString(format);
  }
  return QString::null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Формат даты ни как не отражается на результате.

```
  qint64 y, z;

  y = QDateTime::currentDateTime().secsTo(time);
  QThread::sleep(10);
  z = QDateTime::currentDateTime().secsTo(time);

  y = z-y; // разница в милисекундах
```